# Typescript - Limit keyof to strings

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-hooks

I am trying to create a filter hook, and I want the arguments to the hook to be the data array, the prop that is going to be filtered (filterProp), and the search text.

So I want the data to be T[], the filterProp to be a string representing one of the keys of T, but only string values (so I can do "toUpper" and "indexOf" on them in the filtering. The search text is just a string.

So I tried something like this::

```
export const useFilter = <T, K extends Extract<keyof T,string>>(
  data: T[] | undefined,
  filterProp: K,
  searchText: string
) => {
```

But when I try to "toUppercase" it with it:

```
data?.filter((item) => item[filterProp].toUpperCase().indexOf(searchText.toUpperCase()) > -1) ?? [];
```

It comes up with toUppercase does not exist on type 'T[K]'.

Anybody know how I can limit filterProp to a string value representing one of the string keys of T?

Thanks

Comment: what is the interface(type) of your T and K? can you add it into your question?

Comment: @novonimo Well it shouldn't really make a difference, as I need it to work with all interfaces of T. 

My current interface is: 
`interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  image: Image;
}`

And I just need it to only suggest name as options for filterprop (as it's the only string) and  I need toUpper to work as well when I extract the specified prop from my T object item[filterProp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could constraint `T` to have `K` property with `string` value:

```
export const useFilter = <T extends Record<K, string>, K extends PropertyKey>(...
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wK6uAMQJYA2MwUcAvHADwAqcoxyAJqnAErBJSOUDSANHHRQ8yAOYA%20ATzogGzOAAUoEMCRgBPHsHXiAFACg4RuIwCGMUwC441ANoBdOAB84GJsABmI4Iz6HjXkQkSirW-P5G2KZQCAAW1PTWQiKi%20gCU5OIm5qYA-AB0gcRQurp4xAC2GWRZ5cAVtkXBymD2%20TAQAKpgqlAAwqbYumn5IoygAPIeulEx8fTtXT0kA0NpGVkAtACMGbm5cA4A3EA)

---

Links to utils: [Record<Keys, Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type), [PropertyKey](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L105)

Comment: Thank you very much :) This works yes, only it doesn't help me limit my options of filterProp to only the string type properties of T. I can write any string in filterProp here - I'd love for it to infer that I can use all the keys of T that are string, but none other. Does that make sense?

Comment: @DanielOlsen Isn't it what you're describing? Maybe I'm missing something https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wK6uAMQJYA2MwUcAvHADwAqcoxyAJqnAErBJSOUDSANHHRQ8yAOYA+ATzogGzOAAUoEMCRgBPHsHXiAFACg4RuIwCGMUwC441ANoBdOAB84GJsABmI4Iz6HjXkQkSirW-P5G2KZQCAAW1PTWQiKi+gCU5OIm5qYA-AB0gcRQurp4xAC2GWRZ5cAVtkXBymD2+TAQAKpgqlAAwqbYumn5IoygAPIeulEx8fTtXT0kA0NpGVkAtACMGbm5cA4A3Pr6GqpwOBAQ5HAA3nBWgjDCYgIARtbIGBXvJHAAX304wQBGiwEQKHQ2Qs1iuEAcpywuEIxV0ZgsAgA5KYsdjZnEsRkAPTEuAQADWSOw+CCJQxpmx7zxcCxBNiRLgpJkqgQxEYdCgyigQA

Comment: You are right - I had previously had a case where I could specify keyof T and the "intellisense" would give me all the options so I could select between them. But this doesn't do that, but I guess that might not be possible. Your solution works though, and I get an error if I try a non string - So that's great - Thanks :)